# Finding Facebook profile ID by analyzing the image URL hosted at Akamai

Tags: facebook

I am trying to find out a Facebook profile ID based on the URL of a photo.

The photo, whose link indicates that it has once been (or still is) posted on Facebook.

When I add the photo link to one of Akamai servers, the image loads on my browser. I am assuming that it is still on Facebook. (Or is it?)

I have done a search on the net on how to extract profile id of a Facebook user by looking at the image URL.

However, it looks like Facebook has changed the image URL format, so it's not possible to find the profile ID just by looking at the image URL anymore. (As described here: [Find Facebook Profile Through Image URL](http://returnbinary.blogspot.com/2012/07/find-facebook-profile-through-image-url.html))

The mentioned url is `https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-c.ak/hphotos-ak-ash4/313090_115435085238955_1860750286_n.jpg`

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me to find the profile ID.

Answer (score 9):

The Photos Link download is

```
http://sphotos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/164996_441188405935551_1179878173_o.jpg
```

The Photos Preview will be

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=441188405935551&set=a.152093778152263.30362.100000549253662&type=1&theater
```