# Finding Facebook profile ID from an image URL

Tags: facebook

I was forwarded an anonymous concern about a photo or group site. I want to find the user id as the photo appears to have been removed. The link is `https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155011880340063&set=gm.891218424251397&type=1&theater`.

From that URL, is there a way to find the Facebook user?

Comment: Related: [Finding Facebook profile ID by analyzing the image URL hosted at Akamai](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35477/354)

Answer (score 1):

If the photo has been removed there will not be a way to trace back to the ID (that's a good thing in terms of privacy)

`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155011880340063&set=gm.891218424251397&type=1&theater`

broken down is

`fbid=10155011880340063` The Photo ID

`gm.891218424251397` The Group Permalink Post ID associated with it

Without the UID or Group ID it will be difficult to impossible to trace back the user who posted this.