# How to get Facebook profile ID from saved image

Tags: facebook, profile

I have a Facebook image on my PC that I saved a while ago and would like to find the author (person who posted it), link to profile or user ID. Is that possible?

I tried the following but without success:

- http://graph.facebook.com/photos?ids=1344327517562357
- http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=1344327517562357

Full image name is: 2431550_1344327517562357_1434551231_n.jpg.

Comment: Closely related: [Finding Facebook profile ID from an image URL](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72634/354)

Comment: Thank you, but this is quite different, I dont have image url, only saved name which contains unique image id on facebook, and Im looking for a way to get user id that posted that image :) any help or tip would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Older Facebook photos could be identified using the IDs stored in here `2431550_1344327517562357_1434551231_n.jpg` but this is no longer so for obvious privacy reasons.

So, there will not be a way for you get the owner of this profile just knowing this extension.

More details: http://www.quora.com/Are-Facebook-pictures-really-private-and-are-they-hosted-on-Facebook-servers